# Move and rotate armature so that a bone ends up in specified position?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, transforms, pose-mode

I am trying to make root-motion animation for a simple character. I had already made a forward walking animation and thought I would just alter it to make the turning walk animation. So after rotating an repositioning the first key-frame of the animation I wanted to move the entirety of the armature of the next key-frame so that the foot-IK-bone of my character would end up in the exact same position and rotation as it was in the previous key-frame. But I couldn't find a way to do this. I only managed to set the exact position of just the foot-IK but I wanted the rest of the armature to move with it.

Is it possible to do this or will I just have to reposition the rest of the armature to the best of my abilities if there is no better way to do it?